# Send back list of errors in a template if is not empty

Tags: python, django

I create a view which add data from a file. The function will returns two dictionaries, one with data to be saved and one with data on errors.

I would like to send back to template errors only if there is errors.

Thanks for helping.

My actual code send me back an error: Reverse for 'importXLS.views.import_choices' with arguments '(['miss.....

urls.py

```
path('import_choices/', views.import_choices, name='import-choices'),
# views function
url(r'^data_upload_coa$', views.data_upload_coa, name='data_upload_coa'),
```

view.py

```
def data_upload_coa(request):  # importing chart of account

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the form data from the request.
        company = request.POST.get('company')
        excel_file = {}
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        # return two dictionaries from coa
        accounts, errors = parse_coa(excel_file)

        # Add accounts to chart of accounts table
        for account in accounts:

            # Create a new record with the data if does not exists before.
            upload_data = ChartOfAccount.objects.get_or_create(
                    field_account=account['field_account'],
                    field_account_libaccount=account['field_account_libaccount'],
                    field_type=account['field_type'],
                    field_subtype=account['field_subtype'],
            )
            # company=company,   TO BE ADDED WHEN DEVELOPPING MULTI FIRMS DATA

            # Add save success message

        messages.success(request, 'Chart of accounts updated')

        test = len(errors)

        if test == 0:

            return redirect(import_choices)

        else:

            return redirect(import_choices, errors)

    else:
        # error message
        messages.info(request, 'Uploading error')

    return redirect(import_choices)
```

import_choice.html

```
{%  extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{%  block title %}Import Choices{%  endblock %}
{%  block heading %}<h3 class="page-header-center">File to import</h3>

{%  endblock %}

<hr>
<hr>
{% block page %}
    <script> // logic for validation of file
                var _validFileExtensions = [".xlsx", ".xls"];
                function Validate(oForm) {
                    var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
                    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
                        var oInput = arrInputs[i];
                        if (oInput.type == "file") {
                            var sFileName = oInput.value;
                            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                                var blnValid = false;
                                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                                        blnValid = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (!blnValid) {
                                    alert("Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
</script>
    <script> // Recupere le path du fichier

                var file = document.getElementById("upload");

                file.addEventListener("change", function() {
                    for (var i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++) {
                        console.log(file.files[i].name);
                    }
                }, false);
    </script>

    </br>
    </br>
<div class="container">

    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title col-md-6">Please choose a type of file to import:</h4>
    </div>
    </br>
    </br>
    <!----------------Accordeon ----------------->
    <div class="panel-group col-md-6" id="Choices" >
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" data-target="#Choice-COA" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Choices">Chart of Accounts</h3>
            </div>
            <!--accordeon part 1 -->
            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="Choice-COA">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                            <div class="row col-md-4" >
                                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'data_upload_coa' %}" method="post" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false" onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Company Name " name="company" id="company" required>
                                                </td>
                                                </br>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="file" title="Upload excel file" name="excel_file" id="myfile" required="required">
                                                </br>

                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Upload</button>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </br>
        <!--accordeon part 2 -->
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title" data-target="#import-bv" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Choices">Balance of verification</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="import-bv">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>To be complete Balance of verification
                            test</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Result should be:

- If errors dictionary is empty go back to import_choice.html
- If not: go back to import_choice.html with list in errors shown

Answer (score 0):

in my views. I modified:

```
if test == 0:

    return redirect(import_choices)

else:

    return render(request, 'imports/import_choices.html', {"errors": errors})
```

and in my html file at the end:

```
{% if errors %}
            <div class="panel-body">
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped col-md-3">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <th>Accounts with error</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        {%  for err in errors %}
                            <tr>
                            <td scope="row" class="col-md-3">{{ err|capfirst }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                     </tbody>
                 </table>
            </div>

{% endif %}
```